# Who is the longest surviving characters in Game of Thrones series?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Given frequency how most of the characters are killed in book series and in universe, who are longest surviving characters in series?
For example the ones having longest screen-time, having survived most of the books.

Comment: You really need to expand on what you mean by "longest surviving". Oldest? Most screentime without dying?

Answer (score 6):

If you mean longest living as in the one who has lived the longest physical years, the answer is probably Aemon.

If you mean who has survived the killing that have taken place throughout the books, then there would be several runner ups that would share first place as they have been alive since the first book.

[Character age chart.](http://iamnedstarksmissinghead.tumblr.com/post/44802728962/game-of-thrones-character-age-chart-when-the)

[Another age chart.](http://www.lolbrary.com/Funny/Game-of-Thrones-characters-ages-vs-the-a/48935)

[Proves Aemon is older than a lot of characters.](http://towerofthehand.com/reference/compendiums/appendix_ages.html) Proves he his 102.

[From the wikia:](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Aemon)

> Around one hundred years old, Aemon is thought to be one of the oldest
>   living men in Westeros, though he has retained all of his wits and his
>   mind is still very sharp.

Aemon unless you count wights, or giants or even the cold walking people,is the oldest at 102 years of age.

[Canon proof](http://viewers-guide.hbo.com/game-of-thrones/season2/): That is the were the wikia say they got their information from.

Comment: Have you read the books?

Comment: Yes, I read the first book and part of the second book. I was going to bowdlerize it for my own edification so that I can read it. Why do you ask,I didn't dig into the books for a answer is that the reason.

Comment: Old Nan might be even older than Aemon -- she was an old woman when Ned Stark was a child. She's not on TV though, only in the books.

Comment: *cough* Allsortofcharactersfrombeyondthewall *cough* Sorry, there was something in my throat.

Comment: @MikeScott unless we know old nan's age then she doesn't count. Also it is only proven that she was alive to be the nursemaids of Ned and his siblings and his children.

Comment: @iliveunderawesomerock Because spoilers, but I'll say no more since you haven't read all of the books.

Comment: @MikeScott: What makes you think Old Nan is not in the show?

Comment: Aemon is not older than his uncle, [Brynden Rivers](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Brynden_Rivers) who was born 175 AC (compared to Aemon being born 183 AC)

Comment: @VincentSavard A bad memory, I expect. I checked IMDB and you're right, she was in two episodes.

Comment: gameofthrones.wikia.com is not a very reliable source. I have on many occasions found them to invent stories without quoting a source, and sometimes claim false things. In the linked article about Aemon, they seem to claim that Aerys II was Aegon V's son, which is not correct, unless the tv-show decided that "grandson" was too complicated of a concept.

Comment: **BOOK SPOILERS**: As an addition, we also don't know Melisandre's true age either. She could be a glamoured old woman (some even believe she's Shiera Seastar, making her at least around BR's age).

Answer (score 1):

Lord Bloodraven (Brynden Rivers) is the oldest living man in Westeros.
He is the Last Greenseer that Bran found in the caves of the Children.

Lord Bloodraven was middle-aged by the time Aemon was born.

Comment: Your answer is technically correct, but a source or reference could help improve it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this question is asking who the oldest "human" character is in the series. As for that we have three possibilities.

## [Maester Aemon](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Aemon_Targaryen_(son_of_Maekar_I))

According to his [age calculation](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Years_after_Aegon%27s_Conquest/Calculations_Ages#Aemon_.28Targaryen) he was born in 198 AC but I can't seem to track the source for this in The World of Ice and Fire. He dies in 300 AC which would make him 102 at his death.

## [Melisandre](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Melisandre)

Her age is left deliberately vague but the following article in Entertainment Weekly shows that she's likely over 100 years old and possibly up to 400 years old though we don't know.

> In previous media reports, van Houten has suggested Melisandre is **at least 100 years old, and could be as much as 400 years old.** But Podeswa says the show’s producers **did not want to suggest a specific age.**
>   “The idea is there’s an indefinite indeterminate quality that she **could be ancient**,” Podeswa says. “We were limited by choosing to use a real person rather than a complete CG creation. Because **what does a 400-year-old person look like?** We don’t know. So if you try to create that, then you’re creating something that looks beyond our known reality. Here you feel like she’s very old without putting a number on it.”
>   <sub>[Entertainment Weekly, Game of Thrones director explains Melisandre's age surprise](http://ew.com/article/2016/04/25/game-thrones-melisandre-premiere/)</sub>

## [Brynden Rivers](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Brynden_Rivers)

Brynden was born in 175 AC as is explained in The World of Ice and Fire.

> Both younger and prettier than Lady Barba (albeit far less buxom), as well as more modest, Missy had a kind heart and generous nature that led even Queen Naerys herself—as well as the Dragonknight and Prince Daeron—to befriend her. During the five years of her "reign," Missy bore the king three bastards, most notably the boy **Brynden Rivers (born 175)**, later called Bloodraven.
>   <sub>The World of Ice and Fire, The Targaryen Kings: Aegon IV</sub>

He was presumed dead in 252 AC making him 77 at his "death". However, it is assumed that he is the three-eyed crow that Bran and co meet north of the Wall. This would then make him 125 AC in 300 AC and so older than Maester Aemon.

> The last greenseer, the singers called him, but in Bran's dreams he was still a three-eyed crow. When Meera Reed had asked him his true name, he made a ghastly sound that might have been a chuckle. "I wore many names when I was quick, but even I once had a mother, and the name she gave me at her breast was Brynden."
>   <sub>A Dance with Dragons, Bran III</sub>